# How to append an attribute-value pair on an existing json11 object (c++)?

Tags: c++, json

For example,
I'm building a json message using following code:

```
json11::Json my_json = json11::Json::object{
    { "key_val1", val1},
    { "key_val2", val2},
    { "key_val3", val3},
    { "key_val4", val4 }
};

std::string message = my_json.dump();
```

But if i want to have this json11 object contain different attribute-value pair based on some condition then I've to repeat the same code multiple times.

Is there any way to append attribute-value pair to an existing json11 object?
So that i can build a base object and then append necessary attributes on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

```
json11::Json::object my_json = json11::Json::object{
    { "key_val1", val1},
    { "key_val2", val2},
    { "key_val3", val3},
    { "key_val4", val4 }
};

my_json["newattribute1"] = "newValue1";
my_json["newattribute2"] = 2;

json11::Json json_final = json11::Json{ my_json };
std::string message = json_final .dump();
```

In your case my_json is an instance of json11::Json. In my case my_json is an instance of json11::Json::object.

**json11::Json::object is originally a std::map.**